# Crosswalk Error about "Request was denied for security"

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I use cordova 6.3.1 and crosswalk of cordova plugin 2.1.0 in Android App.
I use self certification in server.
When I send http post request from cordova app to server, "Request was denied for security"  message appeared in screen bottom possion and http post request is fail.
I can send http post request using old crosswalk of cordova plugin(1.5.0).
Do you know someone solutions.
※Following site method is not work
  http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/

Comment: Do you use debug app ?

Comment: Yes. I build debug mode(=cordova build android & cordova run android).

Comment: have you find the solution yet?

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I'm getting this issue and tried everything already

Answer (score 6):

I had the same Toast message displaying Request was denied for security. For me it was also certificate related but the solution was unexpected. The system time of my device was off by quite a bit (almost a year) and this caused the ssl communication to fail. Correcting the time solved it for me. (Thanks to the Google accounts page, which also encountered the same error in the browser and gave a very nice explanation about the reason.)

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue with a crappy Android phone that for some reason wasn't updating the time automatically and was off by several years

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the last 3 lines of the following snippet to **config.xml**:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Try to **remove** the **meta tag** for CSP (Content Security Policy), and add the lines below in **config.xml**:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Also, I have installed the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and the crosswalk-lite.
Run `cordova clean` before build your android app.

I hope it helps!

**--- EDIT ---**

The above solution only worked in debug mode for me.
So, I found a work around using [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate](https://github.com/danjarvis/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate/issues/1#issuecomment-281988879) with Crosswalk version 18+!

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answer's work, check the date/time and timezone

Answer (score 0):

I had my url wrong(Custom domain) with a spelling mistake and you can also check whether the ssl certificate is valid, it gives error, when your ssl certificate is expired.