# Crosswalk XWalkView : Request was denied for Security (Android 7.0 and greater)

Tags: android, crosswalk, xwalkview

I am using Crosswalk XWalkView as my application's webview, now I am loading some website that has valid certificate and works fine in Android versions < 7.

But with Android 7.0 and greater I get this toast message **REQUEST WAS DENIED FOR SECURITY**

and this log

```
06-12 17:46:46.024 22518-22731/? I/X509Util: Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I read some similar questions like this, but the solution being posted is in Cordova (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035794/crosswalk-error-about-request-was-denied-for-security#40974821)). I am using native android and I would like to know if how can I do this on my end (native).

quote from the link

> I solved this by adding the last 3 lines of the following snippet to config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

Thanks!

Basically what I want to do is to have some whitelist like Cordova does, but I don't know if how can I achieve this using Native Android and Crosswalk. First, I don't know if there's a config.xml in native android (in cordova there is), now I really need to know on how can I implement this in my project.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you mean by "using native android". Do you mean you are using JNI C++ (the usual meaning) or some other native framework. Calling "Java" native on Android I always found a bit silly. What your getting is an X509Certificate error, which can be fixed in Webview. Xwalkview I will have to check.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'll change the description, I'm using java. What I want to do is to have a config.xml like what cordova does.

Comment: @JonGoodwin yes it can be fixed if I used the WebView, however, I'm using the XWalkView and it seems like it's an open issue in a dead project: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7375. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035794/crosswalk-error-about-request-was-denied-for-security#40974821 says they were able to resolve it by adding some lines in config.xml, I want to do have that, but I am not using Cordova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by by following the steps from [android network security config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) I trusted additional an certificate.

Basically, the first time I tried it I was providing the wrong SSL certificate (I assumed that it was the website itself, but the one causing the error is a host for a Javascript file being loaded in the website) in my network_security_config.xml.

> website_ca is the SSL certificate file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/website_ca"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

It works fine now.

Comment: I did last year and I no longer have this file, sorry @Waleed but you can search on how to fetch 'ca' from websites

Comment: actually i have local site so its compulsory to add ssl certificate in raw folder?

Comment: how can i extract ssl from local site any idea?

Comment: Do you know Where can I add the certificate in my ionic project? thanks